# Run service on boot debian

Tags: debian, boot, service

I appreciate this has likely been answered but I am struggling to find the answer. I am on Debian 10 and I have a service that I start with the command "service nifi start".

How do I get this to run on boot? The only resources I keep seeing coming up is how to run a shell script, but I want to run a service not a script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian 10 uses the systemd. Just use `systemctl enable nifi.service` command to enable autorun of service.

Also the systemd has series of articles - [Systemd for administrators](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). Highly recommend to read it.